# SSh client in C# .net

Tags: ssh, expect

I want to write a program that accesses my routers and perform some command, while its output is save to file on my disk. I have done this successfully using python pexpect module in linux. I am starting C# .net and want to try over it. Searching google gave me some result on ssh client, but i dont know if any of them can get me the result back ?

Any ideas, i know i shouldnt be asking for any code snippet, just point me in right direction specially if someone has used it to fetch configurations off ssh servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH Library for creating SSH connections in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622278/ssh-library-for-creating-ssh-connections-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8):

You may try the [SSH.NET library](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/).

Comment: +1 for that. I've been looking for something similar myself! :)

Comment: its perfect library for SSH its already using by a lot of big companies

Comment: Sir, i have visited the site. I know i am asking a very dumb question but how shall i use this in my code ? i downloaded the .dll but how to use it ? i know this is a very stupid question but pls guide me. do i need to download the .dll or something else from that site ?

Comment: @user1068846, yes, you should reference the assembly in your project. If you don't know how to do this I would strongly recommend you reading some .NET tutorial first.

Comment: If you are VS 2010 or VS 2012, you can get it via Nuget. Open Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console and type `Install-Package SSH.NET`.