# .net - Executing a process in Unix machine from windows mahcine remotely

Tags: c#, .net, unix, remoting, psexec

I am developing a C# application from which I need to execute a process in a Unix machine remotely. How I can do this with either PsExec or Windows Management Instrumentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both WMI and PSExec rely on Windows-specific APIs and services. Look at Secure Shell (ssh) instead. See [C# Library for SSH and Telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881587/c-sharp-library-for-ssh-and-telnet) or [SSh client in C# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292470/ssh-client-in-c-sharp-net) for C# libraries for using SSH.

Comment: Tell me one thing, Can i use this library from web application?

Comment: @MidhunlalG You can but the connection may take some time to authenticate and the process to execute. This may exceed the time out for request handling. Was there a particular reason or problem you were thinking of?

Comment: The basic idea is I have a web page and on a button click in the page, I need to execute a script located in the Unix machine.

Comment: @MidhunlalG Then, as long as the web app has access to the credentials needed to authenticate to the target system and the script does not take too long, you should be fine.