# How to ssh using c#

Tags: c#, ssh, connection, 3d-secure

I have one question regarding ssh in c#. How can I do the following:

1- Connect to the node using ssh (secure connection with port 22). 
2- Give some commands. 
3- Read the output.

I tried many things in the web but unfortunately nothing works fine. Please help

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292470/ssh-client-in-c-sharp-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622278/ssh-library-for-creating-ssh-connections-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

There are some good open source libraries, for example
http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

You can find examples by looking at the test cases included in the source code.